# Using Python 3.10, but Pyright LSP throws error "Pyright: Alternative syntax for unions requires Python 3.10 or newer"

Tags: python

Pyright LSP throws the following error:

```bash
Pyright: Alternative syntax for unions requires Python 3.10 or newer
```

when using unions while typing Python code. Example:

```py
class Example:
    def method(self) -> str | None:
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, create a `pyrightconfig.json` in your project root, if you haven't already, and set the `pythonVersion` to the version of Python you are using. Must be `3.10` and up.

Example `pyrightconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "include": [
    "src",
    "tests"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/__pycache__"
  ],
  "venv": ".venv",
  "venvPath": "./.venv",
  "reportMissingImports": true,
  "reportMissingTypeStubs": false,
  "pythonVersion": "3.11.3",
  "pythonPlatform": "Linux"
}
```